# Img fitting into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my `body` tag of the page i have a div that contains multiple images (each img has an id of movie, so like movie1, movie2, and so on) that will have a slide show effect. I don't know why this isn't working but instead of having to give each individual img the `css` tag of `max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%` to fit the div correctly in my `jQuery` i put `$('img[id^=movie).css('max-width', '100%', 'max-height', '100%'`, but this isn't working. This code should see that any img that has the word movie in it (all of them do) should have these max tags for it so it can fit the div. Why isn't this working?

Comment: when applying styles and behavior to an element you can leverage the id and class parameters. ids are used to uniquely identify an instance while a class is used for general use. in your example id="movie1" class="movies", where the common styling and behavior should be applied to the movies class and any one off style or behavior can be applied to the id.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `.css( propertyName, value )` syntax for setting mutliple css properties.This can be used only for setting value to a single css property

To set multiple css properties, you should pass an object of property-value pairs of css properties.
`$('img[id^=movie]').css({'max-width': '100%', 'max-height':'100%'})`

source:http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

`movie` should be in quotation marks, it needs a string.